# How to find the ID of which submit button is submitted in javascript ( Without Editing HTML how to archive in Scripts)

Tags: javascript, dom

We have multiple forms with different IDs but same onclick function .

For Like ,

```
<input type="button" id="a"  value="SUBMIT"  onclick="fnSubmitForm();">

<input type="button" id="b"  value="SUBMIT"  onclick="fnSubmitForm();">

<input type="button" id="c"  value="SUBMIT"  onclick="fnSubmitForm();">
```

How to find the ID of which submit button is submitted.

Comment: I have edited the answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in `this` to the function:

```
onclick="fnSubmitForm(this);"
```

and you can pick up the `id`:

```
function fnSubmitForm(el) {
  console.log(el.id);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/swvrn039/2/)

EDIT

Ok, since you can't edit the HTML, here's a script only solution:

```
// pick up the input elements with type=button
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');

// add click events to each of them, binding the function
// to the event
[].slice.call(buttons).forEach(function (el) {
  el.onclick = fnSubmitForm.bind(this, el);
});

function fnSubmitForm(el){
  console.log(el.id);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/swvrn039/9/)

Comment: we dont have access to edit html only access for script .then how

Comment: @GobinathMahalingam: Which browsers do you want to support?

Comment: @FelixKling, not sure if this is a duplicate since all the information wasn't in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

add the function in the onclick like this

```
<input type='button' id='a' value='submit' onclick='fnSubmitForm()'/>
<input type='button' id='b' value='submit' onclick='fnSubmitForm()'/>
<input type='button' id='c' value='submit' onclick='fnSubmitForm()'/>
```

then get the passed value using the following snippet.

```
function fnSubmitForm(){
    console.log(this.document.activeElement.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Comment: @ Sarim Javaid Khan : we dont have access to edit HTMl only access for Script files . then how to find the id ,without adding "this.id" in onClick

Comment: Sorry. It was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Edited the answer. You can also have a check that this element is the same having onlick attribute's value as the function name to be very particular.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
onclick="fnSubmitForm(this.id);"
```

and get the value with the first function argument

```
function fnSubmitForm(id) {
  //your code
}
```

Comment: Don't downvote this answer , Tareq is right.